# reprojecting geotiffs to spherical mercator using gdalwarp

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system

I would like to reproject raster images (tiffs+proj+tfw) files too "google's" projection using gdalwarp.  From what I understand, google uses epsg:900913/epsg:3785.
What I don't know is how to correctly state the source projection.
I believe that UTM32N=epsg:32632.  If I reproject using gdalwarp -s_srs epsg:32632 -t_srs:epsg:900913, would that be correct? If I open that file in global mapper, how do I adjust project and worldfile then?

This is the content of my .proj file:

PROJCS["AUT-UTM32N",
    GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",
        DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
        PARAMETER["false_easting",500000.0],
        PARAMETER["false_northing",0.0],
        PARAMETER["central_meridian",9.0],
        PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
        PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0.0],

This is the .tfw file:
    2.5000000000
    0.0000000000
    0.0000000000
    -2.5000000000
    550001.2500000000
    5199998.7500000000
    UNIT["Meter",1.0]]

Answer (score 3):

The source projection should be read from the file, so you shouldn't have to state it.  Try "[gdalinfo](http://www.gdal.org/gdalinfo.html)" on the source file, and if it returns the proper projection, you are all set!

Answer (score 0):

As Jason Birch pointed out in a recent answer to a similar post, if you want new .tfw files, you can specify a creation option to build new world files.  -co "TFW=YES"

If you don't specify this, the output will be a geoTiff and you won't need (or want) the old world files because they will be in the old spatial reference system.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like your proj file is incomplete (or something was lost in pasting). In general if you want to workout an epsg code from a proj file you can go to http://prj2epsg.org/search and either upload the file or paste in the codes.

After some poking around it looks like your input projection might be epsg:32632 http://prj2epsg.org/epsg/32632